# Forces and point of application

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, vectors, free-body-diagram

Let us consider a rod and two forces acting on it that are not concurrent, that is, to say that their points of application are not identical, but they intersect somewhere outside the rod. Now, if we theoretically find the direction of the resultant $P$ from the point where both the lines of action of forces are intersecting, will it act in the same direction as the real resultant $R$ (that is, the the force or resultant acting on the rod caused by the two forces as mentioned before)?

Is there any theorem or proof in which this matter is explained?
[image]

> Will the direction and magnitude of $F$ and $R$ be as in the image?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135041/discussion-on-question-by-mskb-forces-and-point-of-application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can slide any force along its line of action (parallel line through the point of application) and it does not change the system.

In your case $R$ is going to be along the line of action where it intersects the rod. As shown below:

[image: fig1]

Note that $F$ and $R$ must have the same magnitude and direction.

Comment: Is this concept identical to principle of transmissibility of forces?

Comment: Yes, it is the same principle.

Comment: Had a misconception about this topic.....i thought this whole thing is occuring outside the body