# What is the significance of sliding a force vector?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, notation, statics

**Scenario 1:**

[image: enter link description here]

Here $AB$ is the line of action of the force $\underline{u}$, and $AB$ passes through the center of mass of an infinitely long rigid and uniform bar. Here, $\vec{CD}=\underline{u}$. Now, if $\vec{CD}$ is slid and $\vec{CD}$ becomes $\vec{EF}=\underline{u}$, the physical effect will remain the same. In other words, it doesn't matter whether the $\underline{u}$ vector acts at the point $C$ or the point $E$, the effect on the bar will remain the same. So, in this scenario, there is utility in the existence of the line of action $AB$.

**Scenario 2:**

[image]

Here $BA$ is the line of action of the force $\underline{u}$, and $BA$  passes through the center of mass of a rigid and uniform bar. Now, let a force $\vec{OA}=\underline{u}$ act at point $O$ of the bar. Now, as force is a sliding vector, we can slide $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OA}$ becomes $\vec{BC}$. However, I have a problem here. There is no physical meaning/significance to the vector $\vec{BC}$ as there is to $\vec{OA}$, unlike scenario 1. According to this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/624008/260477), $\vec{OA}$ can be slid along its line of action, and $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{BC}$ have the same effect on the bar. However, to reiterate, I believe that there is no physical meaning to $\vec{BC}$ as neither $B$ nor $C$ are points on the bar. $\vec{OA}$ acts on the bar and has a physical meaning since $O$ is a point on the bar. However, $\vec{BC}$ is acting on literally nothing, unlike $\vec{OA}$, so what is the physical meaning of sliding the vector $\vec{OA}$ in this case?

**My question:**

1. What is the meaning of sliding $\vec{OA}$ in scenario 2?

---

[This](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-force-called-a-sliding-vector/answer/Angelos-Tsirimokos?ch=10&oid=75365659&share=c657c73d&srid=hsEOt&target_type=answer) might help you in answering my question.

Comment: Related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/979623/768162) of MSE and [publication](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~faris/vector5.pdf) of the university of Arizona.

Comment: [Might be worth looking into](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/584318/what-is-the-physical-difference-between-torque-vs-torque-about-a-line) .

Comment: @Buraian Just to let you know, I started a bounty.

Comment: I've tried writing an answer, but most likely it won't be satisfactory.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4408053/768162) MSE post.

Comment: Same post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4408051/768162)

Comment: These helped me find a satisfactory answer for myself: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4408023/768162), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T49f4.jpg), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700494/260477)

Answer (score 1):

Too long to post as a comment.

1. > **Scenario 2:**
   >
   > Now, as force is a sliding vector,

   Please carefully read [my
   answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/698387/8446) to your
   previous question, in particular

   > > 3. $\;\ldots$ Here,
   > >    clearly $\vec F$ and $\vec{OA}$ are “**free** vectors”.

   and

   > > The moral is this: after the physical scenario has been mathematically modelled (abstracted), the classification system
   > > <**free vector** versus **sliding vector** versus **bound vector**>
   > > is unnecessary; instead, carefully respecting the phrasing and
   > > conditions of definitions and theorems ensures that steps performed
   > > are valid.
2. > **Scenario 1:**
   >
   > Here $AB$ is the line of action of the force $\underline{u}$, and $AB$ passes through the center of mass of an infinitely long rigid
   > and uniform bar. Here, $\vec{CD}=\underline{u}$. Now, if $\vec{CD}$
   > is slid and $\vec{CD}$ becomes $\vec{EF}=\underline{u}$, the
   > physical effect will remain the same. In other words, it doesn't
   > matter whether the $\underline{u}$ vector acts at the point $C$ or
   > the point $E$,

   In this (mathematical) scenario as described,

   - $\vec{CD}$ and $\vec{EF}$ are really the same object;
   - $\vec{CD}$ is not "acting" at any point in particular (its name does not signify that it acts at point $C$)
   - there is no physical effect to speak of (none has been indicated).

Comment: "$\vec{CD}$ is not "acting" at any point in particular (its name does not signify that it acts at point $C$)" - See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700494/260477).

Comment: "And yes, a dog named Brownie can well be fully white."- what does this mean? I searched for it and found no relevant [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+dog+named+brownie+can+be+white&oq=A+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j0i67j69i60l4.3296j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic What's your point? Read your own premise/setup/description (note the meaning of "In this (mathematical) scenario as described"); your recent closed question was badly posed because the author (you) failed to communicate the key features of their setup ($O$ not being affixed, etc.), leading every single reader to be answering a different Question from what you actually meant (until I explicitly cleared up the miscommunication).  And yes, a dog named Brownie can well be fully white.

Comment: "leading every single reader to be answering a different Question from what you actually meant"- are you being hyperbolic?

Comment: I was most certainly being literal (though by 'reader', I had meant to write commenter/answerer). My point in mentioning this is to remind you to specify all key features, because otherwise you're just relying on readers to read your mind or to make (unwarranted) assumptions. @tryingtobeastoic

Comment: In my humble opinion, I think that only you and [Robert](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410108/how-to-replace-these-two-forces-with-one-force#comment9227006_4410108) thought $O$ was affixed. Others didn't think that. You might argue that [@Ivan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410108/how-to-replace-these-two-forces-with-one-force#comment9226844_4410108) also thought $O$ was affixed; however, judging from his [first comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409056/how-will-the-force-act-outside-the-stick?noredirect=1#comment9222771_4409056), I don't think that he..

Comment: ...thought that I meant that $O$ was affixed.

Comment: "My point in mentioning this is to remind you to specify all key features, because otherwise you're just relying on readers to read your mind or to make (unwarranted) assumptions.""- I hope that future posts of mine will not cause confusions among readers.

Comment: 1. *You had to clarify to Ivan*, "@IvanKaznacheyeu Firstly, point O isn't fixed." I *knew* it wasn't affixed *only* because you told me so before I posted my (now-deleted) answer which began by helpfully pointing out this hidden (from the view of all except yourself) assumption. In any case, this point is a red herring, and it actually doesn't matter whether O is affixed as long as we assume that the axis of rotation passes through it; my exact words in the other answer relating to the same problem are "Assume that the rotation axis passes through O".

Comment: 2. As I said, the key point in this Comment-answer, and in the above comments, is about the need for attentive reading and not making unwarranted assumptions. Narrowly focusing on particular/recent examples is just a distraction.     "*I hope that future posts of mine will not cause confusions among readers.*"<---YES, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You realize that the theory of rigid bodies is an *idealization* and not reality. A real force not only has a line of action, but also a point(s) of application, and bodies are elastic and not rigid.

Only in the context of this idealization can you really apply the rule of sliding vectors. You can think of mathematical forces vs. real forces. A mathematical force has magnitude, direction, and the line of action because it imparts also a moment of force (torque) about some reference point.

It is this combination of force and torque that fully describes the loading to a system. Any system of forces that produces the same force and torque is indistinguishable from each other (mathematically). The equations of motion are the same.

Mathematical forces do not have an origin point, they are vectors that belong *somewhere* along the line of action, anywhere would do.

In reality, the reasonable assumption is that a contact force acts somewhere on the surface of the body (where the line of action intersects the body). But other forces may act on different points.

Gravity acts on all particles of the body and thus can be assumed to be concentrated at the center of mass without loss of generality (for rigid bodies).

Buoyancy, aerodynamic forces, magnetism may all have different points where they are acting on away from the center of mass.

But again when dealing with Newtonian mechanics, the point where forces act on does not matter, but the resulting torque about the reference point does. For dynamics problems the reference point has to be the center of mass, but for non-dynamic (statics) problems it can be anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Torque is much unlike force. Torque is an origin dependent quantity meaning that it depends on the point you take it around. If someone asks you "calculate the torque?" First question is, about which point?

Compare this with force: For force, you can calculates net force on a body about any point in space and all points will agree. See John's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/499789/236734).

There is however one particular special case where Torque becomes a sort of origin independent quantity: When net force is zero. [Proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/147949/236734)

So, in principle, if you have a body moving in earth, you could set your origin of coordinate system at some point on mars and ask "how much is this body spinning about this point on mars?".

Once, we have all of that out of the way, what does it mean that we can slide the force vector about all those points and the torque is preserved? It's basically an indirect consequence of the fact that when we calculate the torque using the definition $\vec{\tau} = \sum \vec{r_i} \times \vec{F_i}$, **how the mass is distributed in space has no relevance for the calculation.**